# How to create multiple element inside table using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wish to create something like this :

```
<table>
    <tr>
         <td><div><font>ID</font></div></td>
         <td><div><font>Name</font></div></td>
    </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: ok, but what you have initially? only `<table>` or the `<tr>` ? Do you understand your own question?

Comment: You have to have something initially....is the table going in a div? or do you have your table already?  Like do you just wanna insert rows?  And if so, based on what data?  Your question is very broad...

Comment: PLease show the code you've tried so we can help you from there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like to have HTML in my Javascript so here's how I like to use jQuery with templates:

In my HTML:

```
<script id="hidden-template" type="text/x-custom-template">
    <tr>
         <td><div><font>ID</font></div></td>
         <td><div><font>Name</font></div></td>
    </tr> 
</script>
```

In my Javscript:

```
var template = $('#hidden-template').html();

$('.add').click(function() {
    $('#targetTable').append(template);
});
```

so you have a button with the class "add" and it will add the HTML from the template into the `<table id="targetTable">`